# Cast an object to a class with generics

Tags: c#, .net

I've got an instance of class `B`, which is a specialisation of an abstract class `A<TInput, TOutput>`. There are several variants of class `B`, as I've implemented it with a variety of input and outputs.

`TInput` and `TOutput` are constrained to specific input and output classes, let's call them `I` and `O`.

I am instantiating `B` by using [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx), but since it returns an object, I need to to cast it to `A<I, O>`. I expect this to work as `I` and `O` are base classes (in this case `B<SpecialisationOfI, SpecalisationOfO>`).

This is where it fails as this cast is apparently invalid.

Pseudo code:

```
abstract class I  { }
abstract class O { }

abstract class A<TInput, TOutput> 
  where TInput : I
  where TOutput : O
{ 
  abstract TOutput Foo(TInput bar);
}

class Input : I { }
class Output : O { }

class B : A<Input, Output> { }

A<I, O> instance = (A<I, O>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfB); // <-- fail
instance.Foo(input);
```

Is it possible to make this work? Thank you!

**edit** Based on the answer that I was given, I've solved this by restructuring the code significantly based on the covariance:  I moved `Foo` from `A` to an interface:

```
interface IA<TResult> {
   TResult Foo(object input);
}

class A<TInput, TOutput> : IA<TOutput>
  where TInput : I
  where TOutput : O {

  public TOutput Foo(object input) {
     if (!(input is TInput)) {
       throw new ArgumentException("input");
     }

     return FooImpl(input as TInput);
  }

  protected abstract TOutput FooImpl(TInput input);
}

var instance = (IA<Output>) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
instance.Foo(input);
```

Thank you for sharing your insight with me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with how you're creating the instance - it's a problem with [generic variance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx). What you're essentially trying to do is similar to this:

```
List<object> objects = new List<string>();
```

And the reason it's not valid is that the next line of code might (in general) be:

```
objects.Add(new object());
```

If that's trying to add to a list which is *really* of type `List<string>`, that's bad news.

Now if you change from an abstract class to an interface, and if you're using C# 4, you can use *generic covariance* and *generic contravariance*:

```
interface class A<in TInput, out TOutput> 
  where TInput : I
  where TOutput : O
{ 
  abstract TOutput Foo(TInput bar);
}
```

That's *still* not going to work for your code though, as you're trying to use *both* input and output covariantly. Your `B` class will have a method like this:

```
Output Foo(Input bar);
```

... in other words, it needs input of type `Input`. But if you've got an `A<I, O>` that should be able to work for *any* implementation of `I`:

```
A<I, O> x = new B();                // Invalid, as discussed, to prevent...
O output = x.Foo(new SomeOtherI()); // ... this line
```

Comment: I see! That does make sense. Now, if I have the type of `I`, would it change the scenario?

Comment: I mean in this case the specialisation of `I`. This perhaps convoluted pattern is an attempt of mine to use annotations as a means to associate classes with one another.

Comment: @Zanathel: Sorry, I missed these comments earlier. If you didn't need variance on `I`, it would be simpler, yes - covariance is aided by generic constraints (where `TOutput : O`) whereas contravariance isn't :(